How do I get the enum type of a clang::EnumConstantDecl?
I'm trying to write a clang tool that finds all calls to a function with a variable number of arguments, and returns the type of each argument.
When I pass in a constant enumerator value, for example:
static void foo(char *, ...) {}

enum test {
  TEST_VALUE1,
  TEST_VALUE2
};

void main() {
  foo("bla", TEST_VALUE1);
}

I get this AST for the argument:
DeclRefExpr 0x55933eb553b8 'int' EnumConstant 0x55933eb53ec0 'TEST_VAL1' 'int'

I see how to get the clang::EnumConstantDecl object representing the enumerator TEST_VALUE1, but I don't see how to get the type of the enumeration, enum test.  How do I get that?
Note: This is similar to the question Get function call argument enum type with libclang, but in that case, the argument was a variable of enum type rather than an enumerator, and the posted solution there does not work for this case.

I've taken the liberty of changing the "c++" tag to "c", since I think the intent is for the tool to be examining C code, like in the previous question.

First, I'll note that this answer is sort of a bug fix for
my answer to the previous question.
I failed to test the case of passing an enumerator directly, and if I
had, would have noticed and corrected the problem then.  But here we
are.
Enumerator types in C
In C, the type of an enumerator (the constants inside an enumeration
declaration) is int.  Quoting C17 6.7.2.2 p3:

The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that
have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.

Thus, the primary reason that Clang shows the type of an
EnumConstantDecl in C as int is because the language mandates that
it has that type.
Contrast this with C++17 10.2 p1:

An enumeration is a distinct type (6.7.2) with named constants.

BTW, this also shows why it is important to use the right tag when
asking a question, in this case c versus c++, since these
are different languages and the answer in one case can be different than
for the other.  (The solution code in the earlier question works if the
input language is C++.)
Getting the type of an EnumConstantDecl.
In the AST, we have a
DeclRefExpr.
To get the
EnumConstantDecl,
we call
clang_getCursorReferenced,
which in this case corresponds to the C++ API call
DeclRefExpr::getDecl.
(The question already indicates an understanding of how to do this, so
this is just for completeness.)
Then, to get the
EnumDecl,
we then call
clang_getCursorSemanticParent.
In the C++ API, that would be done with
Decl::getDeclContext
followed by
dyn_cast
to downcast to the subclass that context should be
(e.g., dyn_cast<clang::EnumDecl>(enumConstantDecl->getDeclContext())).
Finally, to get the EnumType corresponding to this EnumDecl, we
call the usual
clang_getCursorType,
which corresponds in this case to the C++ call
TagType::getTypeForDecl.
This is encapsulated in the following procedure that retrieves the type
of an expression in the usual way, except if it is a DeclRefExpr to
an enumerator, it navigates to the enumeration type:
// Like `clang_getCursorType`, but if the cursor is a `DeclRefExpr` to
// an `EnumConstant`, get its `EnumDecl` rather than (e.g.) `int`, which
// is what `clang_getCursorType` would return.
CXType getCursorType_getEnumerationIfEnumerator(CXCursor c)
{
  if (clang_getCursorKind(c) == CXCursor_DeclRefExpr) {
    // Get the declaration that the expression refers to.
    CXCursor referenced = clang_getCursorReferenced(c);

    if (clang_getCursorKind(referenced) == CXCursor_EnumConstantDecl) {
      // Get the `EnumDecl`.
      CXCursor semanticParent = clang_getCursorSemanticParent(referenced);

      // The type of that is what we want.
      return clang_getCursorType(semanticParent);
    }
  }

  // Just get the type normally.
  return clang_getCursorType(c);
}

Background: Declaration contexts
The clang_getCursorSemanticParent function returns the "declaration
context" of another declaration.  All declarations are organized into a
tree that is distinct from the main AST; the declaration tree only
contains declarations.
Furthermore, there are actually two declaration trees, one being
"lexical" and the other "semantic".  These are never different in C, but
in C++, a method defined outside its class body has a lexical parent of
(say) the translation unit, but a semantic parent of its class.
Not every declaration can be a parent (interior node) in the declaration
tree; only those that inherit
DeclContext
can be parents.  But knowing that EnumDecl inherits DeclContext (via
TagDecl) points us toward navigating in the declaration tree.
See Declaration contexts
in the Clang internals manual for more information.
Complete updated program
Below is an updated program that incorporates
getCursorType_getEnumerationIfEnumerator, as well as fixing the issue
that getUnderType failed to check if c itself could yield a type:
// ---------------------------- BEGIN ADDED ----------------------------
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Client data for `getUnderTypeVisitor`.
typedef struct GetUnderTypeData {
  // Underlying type, if any.
  CXType underType;

  // True if we find a type to use.
  bool found;
} GetUnderTypeData;

// Like `clang_getCursorType`, but if the cursor is a `DeclRefExpr` to
// an `EnumConstant`, get its `EnumDecl` rather than (e.g.) `int`, which
// is what `clang_getCursorType` would return.
CXType getCursorType_getEnumerationIfEnumerator(CXCursor c)
{
  if (clang_getCursorKind(c) == CXCursor_DeclRefExpr) {
    // Get the declaration that the expression refers to.
    CXCursor referenced = clang_getCursorReferenced(c);

    if (clang_getCursorKind(referenced) == CXCursor_EnumConstantDecl) {
      // Get the `EnumDecl`.
      CXCursor semanticParent = clang_getCursorSemanticParent(referenced);

      // The type of that is what we want.
      return clang_getCursorType(semanticParent);
    }
  }

  // Just get the type normally.
  return clang_getCursorType(c);
}

// Visitor for `getUnderType`.
enum CXChildVisitResult getUnderTypeVisitor(
  CXCursor c, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data)
{
  GetUnderTypeData *data = (GetUnderTypeData *)client_data;

  enum CXCursorKind kind = clang_getCursorKind(c);

  // The AST node `ImplicitCastExpr` is surfaced in the C API as an
  // "unexposed" kind.  So if we see an unexposed kind, assume that it
  // means `ImplicitCastExpr` and recursively search the children.
  if (clang_isUnexposed(kind)) {
    return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
  }

  // For any other kind, we probably have a usable type.
  else {
    data->underType = getCursorType_getEnumerationIfEnumerator(c);
    data->found = true;
    return CXChildVisit_Break;
  }
}

// Try to get the type of `c` after skipping any `ImplicitCastExpr`
// nodes.  Return true and set `*underType` if we can, and return false
// otherwise.
bool getUnderType(CXCursor c, CXType * /*OUT*/ underType)
{
  // If `c` itself is not unexposed, get its type.
  if (!clang_isUnexposed(clang_getCursorKind(c))) {
    *underType = getCursorType_getEnumerationIfEnumerator(c);
    return true;
  }

  GetUnderTypeData data;
  data.found = false;

  clang_visitChildren(c, getUnderTypeVisitor, &data);
  if (data.found) {
    *underType = data.underType;
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
// ----------------------------- END ADDED -----------------------------

static enum CXChildVisitResult visitFuncCalls(CXCursor current_cursor,
                                              CXCursor parent,
                                              CXClientData client_data) {
  if (clang_getCursorKind(current_cursor) != CXCursor_CallExpr) {
    return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
  }

  static const char *FUNCTION_NAME = "foo";

  const CXString spelling = clang_getCursorSpelling(current_cursor);
  if (strcmp(clang_getCString(spelling), FUNCTION_NAME) != 0) {
    return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
  }
  clang_disposeString(spelling);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < clang_Cursor_getNumArguments(current_cursor); i++) {
    CXCursor argument = clang_Cursor_getArgument(current_cursor, i);
    CXType argument_type = clang_getCursorType(argument);
    CXString argument_type_spelling = clang_getTypeSpelling(argument_type);

    printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, clang_getCString(argument_type_spelling));

    // -------------------------- BEGIN ADDED --------------------------
    CXType underType;
    if (getUnderType(argument, &underType)) {
      CXString underTypeSpelling = clang_getTypeSpelling(underType);
      printf("underType: %s\n", clang_getCString(underTypeSpelling));
      clang_disposeString(underTypeSpelling);
    }
    // --------------------------- END ADDED ---------------------------

    clang_disposeString(argument_type_spelling);
  }

  return CXChildVisit_Continue;
}

int main() {
  // --------------------------- BEGIN ADDED ---------------------------
  CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
  // ---------------------------- END ADDED ----------------------------
  const CXTranslationUnit unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(
        index, "file.c", NULL, 0, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);
  const CXCursor cursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(unit);
  clang_visitChildren(cursor, visitFuncCalls, NULL /* client_data*/);
}

When run on the input:
void foo(int a, ...) {}

enum test {
  ENUM_VAL1,
  ENUM_VAL2
}; 

int main() {
  enum test e = ENUM_VAL1;
  int a = 1;
  foo(a, ENUM_VAL1);
}

It prints:
Argument 0: int
underType: int
Argument 1: int
underType: enum test     <-- got it, again


Thanks for the detailed answer again. My clang tool code is in C++, but the code I'm parsing is in C. So I tried to convert to code example to C++ but I still can't figure it out. I get the clang::EnumConstantDecl type, then I call Decl::getDeclContext to get the context, but I'm stuck there. Not sure how to get the type from clang::DeclContext. I assumed the alternative to clang_getCursorType would get just getType()  but clang::DeclContext doesn't seem to have that.

As this question is tagged "libclang", it is primarily about the C API.  The C++ API is called (confusingly) "libtooling" and has its own tag.  I mentioned the C++ API equivalents just because they can be used to help navigate the C API.  I've added a little more detail regarding C++ API equivalents.  If that's not enough, I suggest asking a new question so this one can remain focused on answering for the C API.

The extra info you added was good enough to figure out what I needed to do. Thanks!
